# Eclipse problems with different Android Layouts

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I created a special layout for one of my activities in the /layout-small folder. The problem is that when I open my default layout (the one for which I have the small version), Eclipse decides to open the small version instead! At this point I go back the 'normal' layout but it's displayed for a 2.7" screen and if I make any change to visualize it in any other screen size Eclipse decides to send me to my 'small' layout while keeping the default one at 2.7". I can change my small layout to any size I want but that really makes no sense at all!

Any help is appreciated. Project CLEAN and restarting Eclipse I already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I also had your problem for managing different screen sizes. The one that I use most frequently is to reorganize my layout folders in the same order as drawables. By this I mean that I create these folders for layout :

***layout-ldpi


layout-mdpi


layout-hdpi


layout-xhdpi***

If you open a layout file from the "layout-hdpi" folder , the default device for displaying the preview will be an hdpi one , like "4.0 480*800 hdpi".

Also. I found it much more time-consuming when adapting to different screens.

Another workaround that I'm really in favor of, is using the Intellij Community Edition for android development and user interface design. Intellij is a very stable and robust IDE based on gradle and is much much smoother than the buggy Eclipse.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you said, you mean I should create a separate folder for each?

Comment: yes. for example, in the "layout-hdpi" folder, you can put the xml layout file that's optimized for hdpi screens (margins, sizes, font sizes , ...). The best part is that the Eclipse and Intellij graphical ui designer, and the android os will automatically choose and display layouts based on these folders.

Comment: but what's wrong with the option I selected? I have everything default in layout/ and I have a specific file in layout-small. I seem to understand from the android doc that this is correct.

Comment: optimizing layouts based on screen quality is more trustworthy than the screen size, because the size and resolution are both important and you should be managed together, not just one of them. also you can take advantage of the layout preview in Eclipse, when it automatically picks the correct layout when you change your preview device. Just try it once and let me know how it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having layout issues then I suggest reading this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
As of API level 13 layout-small/normal/large have been deprecated and you should be using sw<>dp qualifiers.

I have an app that has multiple layouts and my standard layout file is for screens that have the smallest available width like so:
layout (smallest screens)
layout-sw480dp (screens that are slightly larger)
layout-sw600dp (7" tablets)
layout-sw720dp (10" tablets)